# How to load image into the correct row in a list view adapter

Tags: android, image, listview, android-asynctask, adapter

In the following situation: **What is my alternative to using an AsyncTask?**

I am using AsyncTask to load images into an adapter. The adapter row has a number of TextViews and one ImageView. The ImageView is where I load the image. The image is being loaded from the internet. The problem is that when I scroll, the wrong image would show in a row/cell -- until the correct image has had time to arrive. How do I prevent this image mismatching from ever happening? *I am asking this question because I want to understand how this works*: I don't just want to get some library that might do the work for me (many libraries I have already tried, have failed).

Once again, the problem: the AsyncTask causes images to load into the wrong row so that the user can clearly see that the images are looking for their final destination.

I hope the question is clear. For completeness, below is the method that I am calling inside the `getView` method of the adapter to load each image. The method is also inside the adapter. **What is my alternative to using an AsyncTask?**

```
private void loadImage(final ImageView photo, String imageUrl) {
        new AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
                try {
                    Bitmap b = callToServer(imageUrl);//takes long
                    return b;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap ret) {
                if (ret != null) {
                    photo.setImageBitmap(ret);
                }
            }

        }.execute(imageUrl);

    }
```

Comment: You can use piccasso  library

Comment: As the question says: I would like to understand how the process works. But just for kicks: I have already tried picasso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the rows get recycled and so does the image view. Then when the server response returns the image view already belongs to another data object.

There are different approaches to this. My solution is to extend ImageView and keep track of the image you want to load.

```
class RemoteImageView extends ImageView {
   private String _uri;

   public synchronized void loadRemoteImage(String uri) {
       _uri = uri;
       loadImage(this, uri) ; //this is your async call
   }

  private synchronized void onImageLoaded(String uri, Bitmap image) {
       if(uri.equals(_uri)) {  //this will set only the correct image
            setImageBitmap(image);
       }
  } 

}
```

As for your loading function:

```
private void loadImage(final ImageView photo, final String imageUrl) {
        new AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
                try {

                    Bitmap b = callToServer(imageUrl);//takes long
                    return b;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap ret) {
                if (ret != null) {
                    photo.onImageLoaded(imageUri, ret);
                }
            }

        }.execute(imageUrl);

    }
```

And then withing your adapter you should call the loadRemoteImage(imageUri)

I also suggest you combine this with a bitmap cache so as to acccelerate the process of fetching the image and the addition of placeholders :)

Comment: Wow. I completely missed the point on how to solve this. I had no idea it involved so much -- and yet so little, in some ways. Thank you very much for the complete answer.

Comment: This will not solve your problem. You will see flickering images because the first async-call will finish and set the image before the second one arrives. And it does not put the logic into the adapter but into a derived view instead - which is not really a good design.

Comment: I find it more reusable since you don't depend on an adapter.. you can load a remote image anywhere with the exact same logic. I also added placeholders while the image is loading in my own code.. Anyway, the important part is the recycling ..

Answer (score 4):

The most common approach is using the setTag(...) and getTag(...) methods of the view that you create in the adapter. Once created, you add a tag that you need to link to the image that is then asynchronously loaded. When that task is finished, you can check the tag of the view and if it's still the same as when the async task has started you can set the image. Otherwise you can dismiss the image. Remember that the same view is re-used instead of created when you scroll. So the tag will have changed then.

Here's a pretty good example: [Asynchronous Image Loader in Android ListView](http://javatechig.com/android/asynchronous-image-loader-in-android-listview)

Comment: I didn't use this approach and I didn't test it. But it sounds correct so +1. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. I take that back. Out of curiosity I tried your approach since it is much simpler. And it works equal well as best as I can see. So thank you very much. I already accepted the other answer. But yours is so very much simpler. Thanks.